# How to add values from state into a object

Tags: reactjs

I have a object called jiraTicketChartData. The dataset has a data key which have hard coded values. I want to replace those hard coded values with the state variable (jiraticketsData) data. I want to access the pie chart values with those numbers.

Here is how the state data is being used.

[jiraticketsdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn62w.png)

```
const defects = () => {
    const loading = useContext(LoadingContext)
    const snackbar = useContext(SnackbarContext)
    const user = useContext(UserContext)

    const [jiraticketsData, setJiraTicketsData] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
      async function onLoadJiraTicketData() {
        loading.setLoading(true)
        const results = await get(`get_jira_tickets`, user.user)
        if (results.status === 0) {
          setJiraTicketsData(results.data)
        } else if (results.status >=20 && results.status <=30){
          snackbar.statusCheck(results)
          user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
        } else snackbar.statusCheck(results)
        loading.setLoading(false)
        }
        onLoadJiraTicketData()

    }, [])

    const jiraTicketChartData = {
      labels: ['backlog', 'in progress', 'in review'
      ],

      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: [
            'blue',
            'orange',
            'green'
          ],
          data: [1,3,3], ***This data should be replaces jiraticketsData.piechart values***
        }
      ]
    }


  return (!jiraticketsData ? null :
    <PageWrapper title={'Jira Tickets'}>
    <div className="jiraTicketChartContainer" >
    <Pie
          data={jiraTicketChartData}
          options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Open Issues by priority',
              position: 'top',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'left'
            }
          }}
        />
    </div>
    </PageWrapper>

  )
}


export default defects
```

Dev tools props being passed:

[Dev tools props being passed]

updated code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      async function onLoadJiraTicketData() {
        loading.setLoading(true)
        const results = await get(`get_jira_tickets`, user.user)
        if (results.status === 0) {
          setJiraTicketsData(results.data)

        } else if (results.status >=20 && results.status <=30){
          snackbar.statusCheck(results)
          user.setSessionTokenMatches(false)
        } else snackbar.statusCheck(results)
        loading.setLoading(false)
        }
        onLoadJiraTicketData()

    }, [])

 
    useEffect(() => {
      jiraTicketChartData.datasets[0].data = Object.values(jiraticketsData.pie_chart);
  }, [jiraticketsData]);




    const jiraTicketChartData = {
      labels: ['backlog', 'in progress', 'in review'
      ],

      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: [
            'blue',
            'orange',
            'green'
          ],
          data:  jiraticketsData.pie_chart
        }
      ]
    }
```

updated error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pie_chart` is an object so you will have to access the [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like so:

In the useEffect if statement try:

```js
if (results.status === 0) {
    setJiraTicketsData(results.data);
    jiraTicketChartData.datasets[0].data = Object.values(results.data.pie_chart);
}
```

Alternatively you could setup another useEffect hook just for that, but then you will introduce another re-render something to keep an eye on, like so

```js
useEffect(() => {
    jiraTicketChartData.datasets[0].data = Object.values(jiraticketsData.pie_chart);
}, [jiraticketsData]);
```

Comment: didn't seem to work, I also just updated the code to show which props are being passed in the dev tools if that is more helpful

Comment: What kind of datatype are you expecting `jiraticketsData` to hold? if it is an array set the initial state to `[]` instead of `null`

Comment: an array, thanks i'll check  out your above answers. Would the data key value just be data: jiraticketsData.pie_chart[0]?

Comment: What is `jiraticketsData.piechart` ? an array?

Comment: Try `jiraTicketChartData.datasets[0].data = jiraticketsData.pie_chart`

Comment: pie_chart is an array

Comment: so 

data: jiraTicketChartData.datasets[0].data = jiraticketsData.pie_chart ?

Comment: Yes but after looking at your linked image the `pie_chart` array has a different format than yous simple `[1, 2, 3]` desired, give me a few minutes to fix that

Comment: I just update my answer, try the following `jiraTicketChartData.datasets[0].data = Object.values(jiraticketsData.pie_chart);`

Comment: can you check if this is right? I'm not to sure, just updated my answer which has my updated code.

Comment: You should leave the  `jiraTicketChartData` object as is and just change the useEffect code, that object will get the new data as soon as the state is updated

Comment: @stack I wonder if this solved your problem, did you get it to work?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just got this error which is updated in my answer, any ideas?

Comment: and then when I put it in my first use effect it saying it can't read the property type of null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223429/discussion-between-stack-and-ricardo-sanchez).